# Ordering libraries in android gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm implementing a feature which requires accessing 'hidden' android API. I know that I could use Java-reflection but i have a compiled custom android jar with few selected classes which no longer contain 'hidden' field, which allows me to access certain parts of the 'private' android API.

Due to the fact that i need to use 'gradle' to build my project (my teacher's requirement) i have stumbled upon a certain issue.

Currently i have a jar:
android-custom.jar -> which only contains "android.telephony.SmsMessage"

In Eclipse i can change the order of libraries from which the dependencies are taken, but in Gradle it seems that the first library for dependency discovery is taken from Android-sdk.

What i want to do is to use my android-custom.jar on-top of Android-sdk, while excluding both of them at runtime (either Android.jar nor my Android-custom.jar wouldn't be attached to my apk so my apk would use on device Android.jar).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {            
            options.compilerArgs << '-Xbootclasspath/p:/home/open-android.jar'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override the compileDebugJava/compileReleaseJava tasks with your own which includes custom library ordering.  See [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_control_the_order_of_compiletime_classpaths) for a really old post on the same topic, sans Android.

Comment: I had similar idea but i get this: Cannot add task ':compileDebugJava' as a task with that name already exists